# Pass UIEvent from UIView in CCUIViewWrapper to CCLayer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccuiviewwrapper

I have a `CCLayer` with a `UIViewController.view` added to the layer via `CCUIViewWrapper`.

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Book" bundle:nil];
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
wrapper = [CCUIViewWrapper wrapperForUIView:vc.view];
wrapper.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);

[self addChild:wrapper];
```

The view has a UIButton, which ideally responds to Touch event, and call an `IBAction`.

But I can't figure out how to make the `UIButton` call the IBAction in CCLayer. The reason that the button calls an `IBAction` in `CCLayer` is that the action planned to do is to interact with the elements of `CCLayer`.

Can anyone give me some lights?